# "continue" stops script when testing if path exists

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a Powershell script that first gets all our AD Users' initials and a number everybody has been assigned. We have a folder with pictures of every user, where the picture is named this number.

Then it goes through each number and checks if a picture with that name exists. If it does it sets the user's thumbnailPhoto, else it's just supposed to continue to next user.

```
#Code to get all ADUsers and sort them |

foreach {
    $source = "PATH HERE" + $_.number + ".jpg"

    if (!(Test-Path $source)) {
        continue;
}

$image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($source)

#Code to resize image to maximum allowed size and assigning it to user
```

It should be fairly simple and it works great for the first 20 users. Then it encounters one, where the image file doesn't exist, so it supposedly should just continue to next user but instead it stops the entire script.

It's probably right in front of my eyes, but I can't see what's wrong with this.

If anybody could help, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because [ForEach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) is a **cmdlet** and **not a loop**. You either have to use a foreach loop (not the cmdlet) or you solve this using the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423)
 cmdlet:

```
#Code to get all ADUsers and sort them | 
    Where-Object { $source = "PATH HERE" + $_.number + ".jpg" } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # do something
    }
```

Comment: Ohh I thought I wasn't using a ForEach-Object and just the loop. I just realised when you're piping to it, it's automatically a Cmdlet.
Sorry, I'm very new to Powershell.
I'll definitely look into piping through the Where-Object, that looks promising!

Comment: The Where-Object was the way to go, but I had to use:

`Where-Object { Test-Path("PATH.jpg") } | `

Thank you @jisaak